# Symfony 2 : html inside label button with form_widget?

Tags: html, symfony, button, label

I want use a button for in form. Is-it possible to put html inside my label for my button as :

```
<button><i class="fa fa-search"></button>
```

This is the code in my twig file. Look the html code in my label :

```
{{ form_start( form, { 'action': path('abx_base_search'), 'attr': { 'id': 'searchForm' } } ) }}
<div class="input-group">
    {{ form_widget( form.searchText, { 
        'attr': {
            'class': 'form-control search',
            'id': 'q',
            'name':'q',
            'placeholder': 'Search text'|trans 
        } 
    } ) }}
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        {{ form_widget( form.button, { 
            'attr': {
                'class': 'btn btn-default'
            },
            'label':'<i class="fa fa-search"></i>'
        } ) }}
    </span>
</div>
{{ form_end( form ) }}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

Yes You can use like this

```
<button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Submit </button>
```

Comment: Sorry I expressed myself badly. I had forgotten the twig for explanation code :P